# how to run concurrent users using different browsers in selenium for LogIn script

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, grid

I have created login scripts using hub and nodes.

- execute command to start selenium server
- Started a Hub along with selenium server.
- Started multiple Nodes.
- Worked on scripts and run for Firefox.

But, what should I do to run login script for concurrent users using multiple browser ?

Comment: Try to use TESTNG with XML.

Answer (score 3):

This load test article is a great walkthru for your scenario - http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-selenium-load-testing-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout my sample test automation project for OrangHRM using Selenium

https://github.com/qamate/orangehrm-selenium-automation

Below is my TestNG.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="smoke-test-suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<parameter name="ReportLocation" value="reports"></parameter>
<parameter name="remoteURL" value="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"></parameter>
<!-- <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/"></parameter> -->
 <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://www.google.com/"></parameter>
    <parameter name="internal" value="false"></parameter>
    <!--
        <test name="test_ff" >
            <parameter name="OS" value="WIN8_1"></parameter>
            <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
            <parameter name="version" value="34"></parameter>

            <classes>
               <class name="com.qamate.orangehrm_selenium_automation.Tests.LoginTest" >
               </class>
            </classes>
        </test>


            <test name="test_ie" >
                <parameter name="OS" value="WIN8_1"></parameter>
                <parameter name="browser" value="internet explorer"></parameter>
                <parameter name="version" value="34"></parameter>
                <classes>
                    <class name="com.qamate.orangehrm_selenium_automation.Tests.LoginTest" >
                    </class>
                </classes>
            </test>

            <test name="test_chrome" >
                <parameter name="OS" value="WINDOWS"></parameter>
                <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
                <parameter name="version" value="ANY"></parameter>
                <classes>
                    <class name="com.qamate.orangehrm_selenium_automation.Tests.LoginTest" >
                    </class>
                </classes>
            </test>-->
    <test name="test_chrome" >
        <parameter name="OS" value="WINDOWS"></parameter>
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <parameter name="version" value="ANY"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qamate.orangehrm_selenium_automation.Tests.GoogleTest" >
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
<!--
            <test name="reportingTest" >
                <classes>
                   <class name="com.kagrana.base.BaseActionsTest" >
                   </class>
                </classes>
            </test>
            <test name="reportingTest1" >
                <classes>
                   <class name="com.kagrana.base.BaseActionsTest1" >
                   </class>
                </classes>
            </test>
            <test name="reportingTest2" >
                <classes>
                   <class name="com.kagrana.base.BaseActionsTest2" >

                   </class>
                </classes>
            </test>
            <test name="reportingTest3" >
                <classes>
                   <class name="com.kagrana.base.BaseActionsTest3" >

                   </class>
                </classes>
            </test>
            <test name="reportingTest4" >
                <classes>
                   <class name="com.kagrana.base.BaseActionsTest4" >

                   </class>
                </classes>
            </test>
             -->
</suite>
```

In the above example, you can see the way I am specifying different browser combinations for different tests as parameters. From your test class you can read these parameters.

E.g. See below class file.

```
package in.mayurshah.base;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import in.mayurshah.DTO.WebDriverConfig;
import in.mayurshah.util.Log;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import in.mayurshah.DTO.TestCase;

public abstract class BaseActions {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected static Log log;
    protected WebDriverConfig config;
    protected String baseURL;
    protected TestCase testCase;
    private static int testCaseCount = 1;

    /**
     * This gets invoked even before suite starts.
     * @param ReportLocation - Provide location where you want to store the report
     */
    @Parameters({"ReportLocation"})
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite(@Optional String ReportLocation){
        log = new Log();
        log.setReportDirectory(ReportLocation);
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({ "remoteURL", "baseURL", "OS", "browser",
            "version", "internal" })
    public void beforeTest(String remoteURL, String baseURL,
            String OS, String browser, String version, String internal)
            throws IOException {
        this.testCase = new TestCase();
        this.testCase.setExecutionEnvironment("{browser:"+browser+",browserVersion:"+version+",OperatingSystem:"+OS+"}");
        this.testCase.setParentURL(baseURL);
        this.testCase.setTestCaseId("KT"+testCaseCount++);
        this.testCase.setScreenshotDirectory(log.getReportDirectory()+"\\images");
        config = new WebDriverConfig();
        config.setRemoteURL(remoteURL);
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        config.setOS(OS);
        config.setBrowserName(browser);
        config.setBrowserVersion(version);
        config.setIntenal(Boolean.parseBoolean(internal));
        driver = xRemoteWebDriver.getInstance(config, log);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(this.baseURL);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest(ITestResult itr) {
        testCase.setExecutionTime((itr.getEndMillis() - itr.getStartMillis()));
        testCase.setTestCaseName(itr.getName());
        log.addTestCase(testCase);
        try {
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
        try {
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
    }
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(ITestContext itc) throws IOException{
        log.setTestSuiteName(itc.getSuite().getName());
        log.writeReport();
        log.zipAndEmailFile();
    }

}
```

Hope that helps!